# How to add values to dataset from a table/matrix?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, merge, dataset

I need to add values to my dataset according with the values of two columns on the same time

This is a sample of my dataset

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
# Groups:   nquest, nord [15]
   nquest  nord tpens  ireg sector
    <int> <int> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1    173     1  1800    18      1
 2   2886     1  1211    13      4
 3   2886     2  2100    13      3
 4   5416     1   700     8      4
 5   7886     1  2000     9      2
 6  20297     1  1200     5      2
 7  20711     2  2000     4      3
 8  22169     1   880    15      4
 9  22276     1  1200     8      1
10  22286     1   850     8      4
11  22286     2   650     8      2
12  22657     1  1400    16      4
13  22657     2  1500    16      1
14  23490     1  1400     5      1
15  24147     1  1730     4      4
```

I need to add the value of the following table to each individual of the dataset according with the value of the variables `ireg` and `sector` he specifically has

```
             sector == 1   sector == 2  sector == 3   sector ==4
ireg == 1        1944.5       27973.4        5328.4      79542.3
ireg == 2          49.3         561.7         237.1       3132.8
ireg == 3        3785.3       73596.3       13563.1     240420.8
ireg == 4        1661.1        7157.5        2054.2      27174.2
ireg == 5        3016.1       37700.8        6429.1      89338.0
ireg == 6         504.5        8160.5        1386.9      22491.7
ireg == 7         442.6        6954.7        2160.0      32398.8
ireg == 8        3419.0       36172.4        5416.6      89411.6
ireg == 9        2266.7       20603.2        4269.7      74176.9
ireg == 10        551.7        4019.0        1060.2      13843.0
ireg == 11        642.8        9484.3        1569.9      23637.0
ireg == 12       1962.6       17565.5        5863.1     145318.8
ireg == 13        843.9        5562.1        1520.3      19911.1
ireg == 14        308.7         831.5         295.6       4021.4
ireg == 15       2524.2       12507.0        4441.0      75844.6
ireg == 16       2763.3        8485.3        3581.4      49263.3
ireg == 17        607.4        2481.2         555.3       6689.7
ireg == 18       1474.0        2272.0        1217.7      23005.5
ireg == 19       3303.8        6552.2        3444.8      63552.4
ireg == 20       1232.1        3212.3        1449.7      23478.9
```

I've already tried to add them manually using `case_when` for each cell, but they are 80 and it would be too long...

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(VA = case_when(
    (ireg == 1 & nace == 1) ~ 1944.5,
    (ireg == 1 & nace == 2 ) ~ 27973.4,
    (ireg == 1 & nace == 3 ) ~ 5328.4,
    (ireg == 1 & nace == 4 ) ~ 79542.3,
    (ireg == ... & nace == ... ) ~ ....
```

Is there a faster way to do that??

Comment: Reshape longer, then merge by `ireg` and `sector`. Try working through a beginner's R course to get some basic understanding first. Please also add some code to create your data next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your matrix from `mutate()` call:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

dataset %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(VA = m[ireg, sector]) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 15 × 6
#>    nquest  nord tpens  ireg sector     VA
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1    173     1  1800    18      1  1474 
#>  2   2886     1  1211    13      4 19911.
#>  3   2886     2  2100    13      3  1520.
#>  4   5416     1   700     8      4 89412.
#>  5   7886     1  2000     9      2 20603.
#>  6  20297     1  1200     5      2 37701.
#>  7  20711     2  2000     4      3  2054.
#>  8  22169     1   880    15      4 75845.
#>  9  22276     1  1200     8      1  3419 
#> 10  22286     1   850     8      4 89412.
#> 11  22286     2   650     8      2 36172.
#> 12  22657     1  1400    16      4 49263.
#> 13  22657     2  1500    16      1  2763.
#> 14  23490     1  1400     5      1  3016.
#> 15  24147     1  1730     4      4 27174.
```

Example data:

```r
dataset <- read_table("
nquest  nord tpens  ireg sector
   173     1  1800    18      1
  2886     1  1211    13      4
  2886     2  2100    13      3
  5416     1   700     8      4
  7886     1  2000     9      2
 20297     1  1200     5      2
 20711     2  2000     4      3
 22169     1   880    15      4
 22276     1  1200     8      1
 22286     1   850     8      4
 22286     2   650     8      2
 22657     1  1400    16      4
 22657     2  1500    16      1
 23490     1  1400     5      1
 24147     1  1730     4      4")

m <- read_table(col_names = F, "
1944.5       27973.4        5328.4      79542.3
  49.3         561.7         237.1       3132.8
3785.3       73596.3       13563.1     240420.8
1661.1        7157.5        2054.2      27174.2
3016.1       37700.8        6429.1      89338.0
 504.5        8160.5        1386.9      22491.7
 442.6        6954.7        2160.0      32398.8
3419.0       36172.4        5416.6      89411.6
2266.7       20603.2        4269.7      74176.9
 551.7        4019.0        1060.2      13843.0
 642.8        9484.3        1569.9      23637.0
1962.6       17565.5        5863.1     145318.8
 843.9        5562.1        1520.3      19911.1
 308.7         831.5         295.6       4021.4
2524.2       12507.0        4441.0      75844.6
2763.3        8485.3        3581.4      49263.3
 607.4        2481.2         555.3       6689.7
1474.0        2272.0        1217.7      23005.5
3303.8        6552.2        3444.8      63552.4
1232.1        3212.3        1449.7      23478.9") %>% as.matrix()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hi @margusl and thank for the answer! It works perfectly. I didn't know that R was able to assign the right `ireg` and `nace` values automatically

Comment: It can't :) It's just matrix indexing, `m[row_index, column_index]` . You happen to have a matrix of ireq-rows and sector-columns, when evaluating `m[ireg, sector]` ,  `ireg` and `sector` are column names in you dataframe and as we are in rowwise grouping mode,  for each dataframe row corresponding `reg, sector` values are taken from that row and corresponding value is picked from the matrix, `m[18,1]` for the first dataframe row, `m[13,4]` for the 2nd and so forth.

Comment: ok, now its is clear! thank you very much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can just do

```
dat$VA <- m1[as.matrix(dat[c("ireg", "sector")])]
```

-output

```
> dat
# A tibble: 15 × 6
   nquest  nord tpens  ireg sector     VA
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1    173     1  1800    18      1  1474 
 2   2886     1  1211    13      4 19911.
 3   2886     2  2100    13      3  1520.
 4   5416     1   700     8      4 89412.
 5   7886     1  2000     9      2 20603.
 6  20297     1  1200     5      2 37701.
 7  20711     2  2000     4      3  2054.
 8  22169     1   880    15      4 75845.
 9  22276     1  1200     8      1  3419 
10  22286     1   850     8      4 89412.
11  22286     2   650     8      2 36172.
12  22657     1  1400    16      4 49263.
13  22657     2  1500    16      1  2763.
14  23490     1  1400     5      1  3016.
15  24147     1  1730     4      4 27174.
```

Comment: hi @akrun thank you to have shown me also this way. I'm still a newbie about R